# Autowire two Neo4j GraphRepository in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, neo4j, autowired

I'm new to using Spring with Neo4j and I have a question about @Autowire for a GraphRepository.

Most examples I've seen use one @Autowire per Controller, but I have two Nodes I need to modify at the same time when a particular method is called in the controller. Should I simply @Autowire the repositories for both nodes (eg per the code below)? Is there any impact if I do this in a second controller with the same repositories as well (so if I had a ChatSessionController which also @Autowired ChatMessageService and ChatSessionService)?

ChatMessageController.java

```
@Controller
public class ChatMessageController {

@Autowired
private ChatMessageService chatMessageService;
@Autowired
private ChatSessionService chatSessionService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/message/add/{chatSessionId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public void addMessage(@RequestBody ChatMessagePack chatMessagePack,
        @PathVariable("chatSessionId") Long chatSessionId) {
    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(chatMessagePack);
    chatMessageService.save(chatMessage);
    // TODO: Make some modifications to the ChatSession as well
}

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I've been googling and looking through Stackoverflow to understand this better but I haven't found anything yet. Any pointers in the right directions would be great.

Another underlying question is, should I be (and can I?) modifying other Nodes in a GraphRepository that handles a particular node? Eg Should my GraphRepository be able to modify my GraphRespository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced that this is a SO question, it's not really a Neo4J or Spring question either, it is more about the architecture of your application. However assuming that you understand the negatives of class fan out, and how to use the @Transactional annotation to achieve what you want then the answer to your question is that it is just fine to have many Repositories (Neo4J or otherwise, autowired or otherwise) in your class and in as many classes as you want.

Neo4J transactions [default to Isolation level READ_COMMITTED](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions.html) and if you need anything else, you need to add the guards/locks yourself. Nested transactions are consideredd tobe the same transaction. The Spring @Transactional annotation relies on proxies that you should be aware of as they have implications when calling methods from within the same class.

I would go through [this tuotorial](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-graph/snapshot-site/reference/html/#tutorial_repository) over at Spring Data and get your head around how real world vs domain vs node models differ, there will be cases where one repository impacts another node type but I would think it is often transparent to you (i.e adding relationships). You can do what you like in each repository (the generic nature of them is largely confined to all of the built in CRUD and queries derived from finder-method names (see [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/programming-model.html) ) using the @Query annotation, and some queries have side effects, but largely you should avoid it.

As you start adding multiple repositories to multiple controllers I think that your code will begin to smell bad and that you should consider encapsulating this business logic off on its own somewhere, neatly unit tested. I also wouldn't tie myself to one controller per data object, it would be fine to have a single ChatController with a POST/chat/ to create a new session and POST /chat/{sessionId} to add a message. Intersting questions on Programmers:

- [How accurate is "Business logic should be in a service, not in a model?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218011/how-accurate-is-business-logic-should-be-in-a-service-not-in-a-model)
- [Best Practices for MVC Architecture](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/30348/best-practices-for-mvc-architecture)
- [MVC Architecture — How many Controllers do I need?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/208114/mvc-architecture-how-many-controllers-do-i-need)

Comment: Thank you John, that was a very useful answer and gives me a lot to think about. Also, thanks you for your generosity in addressing this question too!